# Random sample of two arrays but with matching indices in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create random samples from two different arrays (y and yp) but with matching indices. This question has already been asked and the reply suggested using np.random.choice on an index array and apply it to both arrays. On this basis I prepared the following code but I am always getting an error message saying only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. I am unable to get this fixed. How to solve this issue?  Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Code:
`idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(y)), len(y), replace=True)
y_s = y[idx]
yp_s = yp[idx]`

Comment: Can you show a bit about `y` and `yp`, I have no issues running this code.

Comment: y = [6.23, 7.55, 8.25, 6.78, 5.16, 5.72, 5.82, 9.74, 8.67, 11.92, 7.33]

yp = [6.470852, 7.322756, 7.54362, 6.786372, 4.956356, 5.713604, 5.839812, 9.405188, 8.900356, 11.51917, 8.711044]

Comment: Ah, they are lists, not numpy arrays.  Use numpy arrays and your code will work fine.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It worked.